# What's the exchange suffix for German and Australian stocks for GoogleFinance API?

Tags: r, google-finance, google-finance-api

What's the exchange suffix for German and Australian stocks for GoogleFinance API? For London stocks, it's .L (e.g. VOD.L). Just wonder what's the suffix for Germany and Aussie?

I tried something like .DE for German but it didn't work..(that's the exchange suffix for Yahoofinance anyway)

btw, below is my code to call GoogleFinance API with R

ticker <- "VOD.L"

a <- getSymbols(ticker, src="google",
           from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), to = as.Date("2017-05-16"))

Answer (score 0):

Here in Australia, our main exchange is the [Australian Securities Exchange (ASX)](http://asx.com.au).

Personally, when I query Google Finance manually (i.e. through the web interface), I write my queries as `ASX:WOW`, [like so](https://www.google.com/finance?q=ASX%3AWOW). Note that some vendors treat this differently. E.g. Yahoo Finance prefers the `WOW.AX` convention (I believe Bloomberg does also, from memory).

Answer (score 0):

Example for Germany (Software AG): **ETR**:SOW or **FRA**:SOW (ETR refers to the Xetra electronic exchange, where a large majority of the volume is nowadays traded. It is also the exchange that is most commonly used for reference data. FRA, on the other hand, refers to the "manual" trading floor. The main reason why you might sometimes want to use FRA is because it has longer trading hours than ETR. See [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/56242) for more details.)

Example for Australia (Australia and New Zealand Banking Group): **ASX**:ANZ